# Is there a library or framework for creating and modifying contacts in iOS ? - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cncontact

I have an app that retrieve employees info from a database (name,number,email,etc..) .

So is there a library or framework to create new contacts or modifying them and adding them to the contacts app in iOS using swift?

[image]

if I want to show employee contact coming from database , should I create UI like this or I there is a library to this ?

Comment: @Pekka 웃 yes I did I know about apple Contacts framework but what I meant is the UI .is there a library providing same UI like contacts app in iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what are you looking for is Contacts framework(iOS 9+). It is provided by Apple and it allows you to create, edit or delete contacts on iOS.

Here you can find [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328).
And [here](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/) you can find decent guide to how to use it.

For versions iOS lower than 9, you can use AddressBook framework. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/). [Guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/63885/address-book-tutorial-in-ios).

Comment: ok thank you , so I need to create UI by myself at the end like in the question ?

Comment: @Zizoo As far as I know, there is no default ViewController that you can just use, as UIImagePicker or something, so unfortunately you have to create your own UI.

Comment: iOS provides UI in the ContactsUI framework. There is CNContactPickerViewController and CNContactViewController.

Comment: @phix23 Thank you so much , that's what I want , shouldn't your comment be an answer ? or just stupid question :)